# Exporting Standalone Interactivity in Adobe Animate

Tags: html, adobe-animate, interactive

*I'll preface this by saying I'm not sure of much of the vocabulary involved here - so I might not know the term I need to be asking about. Nor am I sure that here is the best place to ask it.This is my first shot at working in Animate but I'm pretty well versed in the rest of the Adobe CC Suite.*

I'm working on a proof-of-concept for an interactive map graphic - a map with a two actions:

1. A mouseover event that highlights a map pin
2. An event that slides an info sidebar graphic on-screen when I click
   the map pin.

From what I've found, it seems like Adobe Animate is the best program to build my project in. I've used the following Adobe Animate tutorial to walk me through as much of the process as possible [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/how-to/animated-infographic.html?playlist=/services/playlist.helpx/products:SG_ANIMATE/learn-path:key-techniques/playlist:topic/set-header:animation-further/en_us.json&ref=helpx.adobe.com) - notably I'm most interested in *Step 5 - Adding Interactivity*.

My goal is to be able to export the final graphic as a stand-alone file from Animate to a tablet. I can't seem to understand how to export this as a functioning stand-alone file.

I've accomplished my proof of concept insofar as it functions as intended when I test this via Control>Test Movie>In Browser. However, when I publish the file (JavaScript&HTML) and try to view it (by clicking the exported HTML file) on the same machine there is no mouseover or click functionality and when I test it on another machine, I get an entirely blank webpage. I do not get the same result when I export the tutorial project (it functions exactly as intended).

**Is there a way to export an interactive graphic from Animate in some standalone format and have it function as it does in the test browser of the program - or is Animate even the ideal program to be trying to build this in?**

Comment: I'm not sure how much it matters, but I have minor experience with HTML - usually enough to navigate, tinker and apply fixes.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console when you view the file? Press F12 to see the console. This sort of animation can be easily added after the fact using CSS or JS. There are a lot of other programs that export HTML/CSS/JS with *very* basic functionality. I haven't used the much. [Webflow](https://webflow.com/) probably has the most hype right now.

Comment: See also documentation related to CreaseJS/EaseJS with Animate: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html

Comment: Thanks. To complicate things, the 2020 version of everything just dropped - so I'm seeing if the update changes my issue at all. 

I'm currently getting the error: 
"Uncaught An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.
b._testHit @ createjs.min.js:13
b._getObjectsUnderPoint @ createjs.min.js:13
b._getObjectsUnderPoint @ createjs.min.js:13
b._getObjectsUnderPoint @ createjs.min.js:13
b._testMouseOver @ createjs.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ createjs.min.js:13" 

Looks like local assets might be it.

Comment: Looks like it. If you host your assets and files on a server I'm betting it'll work.